# Issues with pattern searching with `grep` and then replacing in Mac OS

Tags: macos, perl, sed, grep

There are many similar posts available on SO. However, the answers given there do not work for me. I am using Mac OS Monterey with version 12.6.5.

I am searching all the files in a directory that contains a pattern or text-part using `grep`. Then I want to pipe that filename and use `perl -pe` or `sed` along with inline option `-i`. However, it does not work on my Mac!  The minimal code is given below.

```
newprojectname=NEW
oldprojectname=OLD
dir=.
grep $oldprojectname $dir -lr --exclude test.sh 
grep $oldprojectname $dir -lr --exclude test.sh | xargs perl -i -pe's/oldprojectname/$newprojectname/g'  
# Also tried
grep $oldprojectname $dir -lr --exclude test.sh | xargs sed  -i.'' 's/oldprojectname/$newprojectname/g'  
echo `sw_vers`
cat t1.txt t2.txt
```

Output:

```
    ./.test.sh.swp
    ./t1.txt
    ./t2.txt
    sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
    ProductName: macOS ProductVersion: 12.6.5 BuildVersion: 21G531
OLD

OLD
```

You can see the `grep` operation successfully found two files containing the searched pattern `OLD`. However, `OLD` has not been replaced by `NEW`. So that is the issue here.
I am intentionally keeping the unintentionally generated .swp file so that the answer takes care of binary files as well.

Can this be sorted out with a simple modification to my script?

Comment: Can you try: `grep "$oldprojectname" "$dir" -lr --exclude test.sh | xargs sed -i.bak "s/$oldprojectname/$newprojectname/g"`

Comment: Remind me which grep and find comes with MacOS 12.6.5?

Comment: @anubhava That also has been tried. Checked again after you mentioned. No luck!

Comment: @Schwern `grep -V` gives                                               
`grep (BSD grep, GNU compatible) 2.6.0-FreeBSD`.

Comment: What happened when you tried that command? Did you get any error? What is output of `grep "$oldprojectname" "$dir" -lr --exclude test.sh` command ?

Comment: The same output. It additionally generates backup files. That's the difference only.  I am already printing output of the command `grep "$oldprojectname" "$dir" -lr --exclude test.sh`. See my original post.

Comment: Your question also shows `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`. Are you still getting it?

Comment: That happens because there exists a .swp (binary) file. If I remove that, that error will disappear.

Comment: Why don't you exclude the swap files? It does not really make sense to search them. I wonder why you got a swap file in this directory. This is also worth investigating.

Comment: What is the output of `what $(command -v sed)`? I don't have a macOS v12 to test on.

Comment: @glennjackman Output:
`/usr/bin/sed
 PROGRAM:sed  PROJECT:text_cmds-138.100.3
 PROGRAM:sed  PROJECT:text_cmds-138.100.3`

Comment: Hmm, on my Mac, it's version text_cmds-165.80.1 -- the output of `strings /usr/bin/sed` does not contain "illegal byte sequence".

Comment: I do wonder if your sed is old enough to complain about characters appearing after the `$` line anchor in `sed 's/$old ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your script.

First, you've forgotten the `$` on $oldprojectname.

```
... | xargs perl -i -pe's/oldprojectname/$newprojectname/g'
                          ^
                        there
```

Second, as pointed out in the comments, with single quotes shell variables won't be interpreted. Perl will literally get `s/$oldprojectname/$newprojectname/g'`. For something this simple, use `"`.

```
... | xargs perl -i -pe "s/$oldprojectname/$newprojectname/g"
```

For something more complicated, perl and shell quoting can get mixed up, they both use $; you could stick with single quotes and export the shell variables as environment variables.

```
export new=this
expert old=that

... | xargs perl -i -pe 's/$ENV{old}/$ENV{new}/g'
```

---

There's no need to first grep for files containing the old text, it's redundant. You can search and replace every file in one pass. Use `find` to feed Perl the files.

```
find $dir -type f -not -name 'test.sh' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -i -pe 's/$old/$new/g'
```

Files which do not contain $old will be unaffected (verify it doesn't change the modified time, tho).

Comment: Sorry, for pointing out the mistake. However, it still doesn't work. Actually, I tested for for a bigger code and now mistakes happened while writing the MWE version for the SO post. I have corrected. But the problem persists for both the solutions. There might be some issues with `xargs` on Mac. Any alternative avoiding `xargs`?

Comment: I meant "thanks" for pointing out the mistake and I am sorry for having that in my original post.

Comment: When you use single quotes `' .. '` your shell variables are not interpolated. You would have to use `$ENV{old}` for shell variables, assuming they are correctly exported.

Comment: I feel pretty sure that Perl rewrites the files even if nothing is changed in them, when using `-i` switch. That would make a good question on its own.

Comment: @Schwern Thanks. Also, its `$ENV{old}`, not `$ENV[old]`. The latter would try to access `@ENV`, and not `%ENV`.

Comment: @Bork Thanks for the fixes. I've been doing this on a phone, and I jump between so many languages these days.

Answer (score -1):

*I am editing my previous answer here:*

As correctly explained by @Bork, using single quotes is the real issue. Using `export` and Perl's `$ENV` resolves the issue. Therefore, it would have worked if I had used double quotes in my original script.

@Schwern nicely gave the solution in two possible cases (using single and double quotes).

To help other newbies, I am clubbing all the possible solutions as one summary script below.

```
new=NEW
old=OLD
dir=.

#Method 0:
# Change OLD to OLD using `find` and `perl -pe` (substitute with double quotes)
find $dir -type f -not -name 'rename.sh' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -i -pe "s/$old/$new/g"
echo `cat t1.txt t2.txt`

#Method 1:
# Now change OLD to OLD using `grep` and `sed` (substitute with double quotes)
grep $new $dir -lr --exclude rename.sh | xargs sed  -i.'bak' "s/$new/$old/g" && rm -f *.bak
echo `cat t1.txt t2.txt`

export this=NEW
export that=OLD
#Method 2:
# Change OLD to OLD again  using `find` and `perl -pe` with `$ENV`  (substitute with single quotes)
find $dir -type f -not -name 'rename.sh' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -i -pe 's/$ENV{that}/$ENV{this}/g'
echo `cat t1.txt t2.txt`

#Method 3 (not recommended):
# Change OLD to OLD again using `for`-loop for each file matched with `grep` 
for f in\
     `grep $new $dir -lr --exclude rename.sh`  
    do
      sed -i.'bak' "s/$new/$old/g" $f
    done
rm -f *.bak
echo `cat t1.txt t2.txt`
```

Output:

```
NEW NEW
OLD OLD
NEW NEW
OLD OLD
```

Comment: Can anyone kindly explain why I have been voted negatively, would like to point out anything wrong from my end?

Comment: Mainly for the incorrect use of `for` to read the output of grep: [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: Regarding your postscript: the shell does not substitute variables inside of single quoted strings.

Comment: I dv'd because xargs isn't the issue, the for loop just complicates things. The issue is a typo and shell quoting.

Comment: @glennjackman But I am not reading files at all! I just made a list of sorted files with `grep` and looped over it.

Comment: @Scwern You're right.

Comment: No not a file, but a data stream. In your previous answer you were for-looping over the output of grep. Don't do ``for f in `grep -l ...`; do stuff; done``. Do do `while IFS= read -r f; do stuff; done < <(grep -l ...)` or even better `grep -l ... | xargs stuff`